# How to Bind Static Data Using Knockout in MVC

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am Using Knockout With MVC for the first time. I am trying to show the Name and Surname which will be static and will be shown as they are defined in the Controller Class. I had tried my level best to show the Data but it's Output is not as I had expected. My Code is as Follows:
**Model Class**

```
using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout;
using PerpetuumSoft;
using DelegateDecompiler;

namespace MvcApplication20.Models
{
 public class Class1
{

    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

 }
}
```

This is my **Controller Class**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication20.Models;
using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout;

namespace MvcApplication20.Controllers
{
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        Class1 student = new Class1();
        student.Number = "B123456";
        student.Name = "Anubhav";
        student.Surname = "Chaudhary";
        return View(student);
    }

 }
}
```

This one is my **Index Class**

```
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
@model MvcApplication20.Models.Class1   

<h2>Indexer</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<p> Name:<span data-bind="text:Name"></span></p>
<p> SurName:<span data-bind="text:Surname"></span></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function()
 {

     var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))         
        ko.applyBindings(model);
  });
  </script>
```

My Output is like this:

**Name:**

**Surname:**

As you can see it's not showing the Name which I had provided in the coding Section, please help me out and tell me what to do so that I can get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

H,

This is an old post.I answered this because if someone has this issue , my solution will work for them too.

You have to add jquery plugin before the knockout.js plugins.

`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>`

`<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel properties are not knockout observable properties. You can use[knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) . In this case your javascript must be:

```
$(function()
{
 var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))  
 var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Siyamad for answering my question but as far I know We use Observable when we want to make any property editable, but here I am not making them editable, their value will remain same everywhere. But still I applied your code to my JavaScript but it's not working and still now it's not giving the desired output. Can you provide any other solution!

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that all scripts are loaded?
I think this is not correct path (based on the statndard MVC folder locations)

```
'<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>'
```

and this one is might be correct:

```
'<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")"></script>'
```

Comment: Thanks Rustam for answering my question, I had tries your solution also but still it is not giving the desired Result.